# hiding links from users who are not logged on php/mysql

Tags: php

I am wondering how I can hide two links in my main.php page so when i am not logged in, i can't see the links on my main.php page. Below is my code and basically even when I  am logged off, if I type "localhost/main.php" I would still be able to click on those links ( links being  "» Logout" and "   » Creation". How can i make it that when i am logged off, those links aren't visible or clickable to me. thanks in advance. Below are the two codes in my php file:

```
&raquo; <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
&raquo; <a href="creation.php">Creation</a>
```

Comment: And how do you check if user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are logged in I hope you are setting [SESSION](http://php.about.com/od/advancedphp/ss/php_sessions.htm). If you are setting a session when you logged is `$_SESSION['id'] = "SOME VALUE"` then you have to do like this:-

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
  echo '&raquo; <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        &raquo; <a href="creation.php">Creation</a>';
}
```

**The above code explanation :-**

When you click on logout link you have to destroy your session. So when the user is not logged in then it will not get any session, so you have to put a condition if the session is set then only show those link other wise don't show it